# adding controls dynamically

Tags: c#-3.0, coolite

how to add dynamically a menupanel with menuitems inside a accordion using coolite controls toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

you can try my sample here :

```
private void CreateMenu(int index, string title, string url, MenuPanel menuPanel, Panel panel)
{
     MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
     menuItem.ID = "MenuItem" + index;
     menuItem.Text = title;
     menuItem.Listeners.Click.Handler += "addTab(#{TabPanel1},#{" + menuPanel.ID + "},'MenuItem" + index + "',' " + title + "',' " + url + "');";
     menuItem.Icon = Icon.ApplicationForm;

    menuPanel.Menu.Items.Add(menuItem);
    panel.BodyControls.Add(menuPanel);
    Accordion1.Items.Add(panel);
}

private void PopulateMenus()
{
      string[] menus = new string[] { null, "Menu 1", null, "Menu 2"};

      MenuPanel menuPanel = null;
      Panel panel = null;

      for (int i = 0; i < menus.Length; i++)
      {
         if (menus[i] == null)
         {
            panel = new Panel();
            panel.AutoScroll = true;
           panel.ID = "Menu" + i;
            panel.Title = menus[i + 1];
            panel.Border = false;
            panel.BodyStyle = "padding:6px;";
            panel.Icon = Icon.ApplicationCascade;

           menuPanel = new MenuPanel();
            menuPanel.AutoScroll = true;
            menuPanel.ID = "MenuPanel" + i;
            menuPanel.Border = false;
            menuPanel.BodyStyle = "padding:6px;";
            continue;
         }

          CreateMenu(i, "Sub-" + menus[i], "www.test.com", menuPanel, panel);
       }
}
```

Hope it helps.